# Check all elements with the same class are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a simple problem, I have a list with all the same class names, when one is clicked, it animates out of the container and then redirects you etc. It also has a hide button, when I hide them all, I want to have the browser alert me when they are all manually hidden, however, since the list is already hidden on the page until a button is clicked to show the list, I'm not sure if this is messing with my jquery or not.

Html basically goes like this -

```
<ul class="alertContainer"> <!-- Hidden until button is clicked to show -->
  <li class="alert"> </li>  <!-- each are removed one at a time -->
  <li class="alert"> </li>
  <li class="alert"> </li>
  <li class="alert"> </li>
<ul>
```

jquery -

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 if (!$('.alerts:visible').length === 0)
  alert('all are hidden');

 });
```

As the Alerts are already hidden when the website has loaded, I think it's causing a problem, but they become visible when the button is clicked and then they can be placed into a hidden state individually. I'm not sure If it is better to put this block of code inside the code that is used to remove the alerts

jquery to remove alerts individually --

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.alerts').click(function() {
     $(this).animate({ marginLeft: "100%"} , 100);
     $(this).attr("style","overflow-x:visible");

});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.alerts').click(function() {
     $(this).fadeOut(200);
  });
  });
```

If anyone could help me out, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code below and try replacing all the javascript outlined above with it.

Take note the strict use of nesting, use of callbacks, and chaining.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.alert').click(function(event) {
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: "100%"
        }, 100, function() {
            $(this).attr("style","overflow-x:visible");
        }).fadeOut(200, function() {
            if ($(".alertContainer li:visible").length == 0) {
                alert('all are hidden');
            }
        });

    });

});
```